# Using the "minted" package is incomptatible with the cftbeforesecskip command from the "tocloft" package. What can I do to fix it?

Tags: errors, minted, tocloft

I have a relatively large document that has a lot of custom modifications to the table of contents via the `tocloft` package. I want to include syntax highlighted source code through the `minted` package.

However, even just adding `\usepackage{minted}` introduces errors related to the table of contents.

I stripped down the whole document and found that it is related to this command:

`\renewcommand\cftbeforesecskip{\setlength{4pt}{}}`

I don't know what this command does, maybe I can remove it but I would prefer not to. How can I fix this?

Below is a minimum working example, it will compile without the `\usepackage{minted}`, but has an error with it:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftbeforesecskip{\setlength{4pt}{}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{center}
    \tableofcontents
\end{center}

\section{Intro}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Change `\renewcommand\cftbeforesecskip{\setlength{4pt}}` to `\renewcommand\cftbeforesecskip{4pt}`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ, thank you, that seemed to fix it. Do you want to post this as a full answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with `minted`, but only the wrong way in changing value of `\cftbeforesecskip`.

The `tocloft` package doc, sec. 2.2 "Changing the titles" reads

> [marginal note] 
> `\cftbeforeZtitleskip` 
> `\cftafterZtitleskip`
>
> [main text] 
> These lengths control the vertical spacing before and after the titles. You can change them from their default values by using `\setlength`.

Hence you can use

```tex
\setlength\cftbeforesecskip{4pt}
```

The one (`\renewcommand\cftbeforesecskip{4pt}`) in my comment is not recommended and may cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you found

```
\renewcommand\cftbeforesecskip{\setlength{4pt}{}}
```

which is completely wrong. As the manual of `tocloft` specifies, control sequences of the form

```
\cftbeforeXskip
```

where `X` stands for `chap` or `sec` or `subsec` and so on, are lengths.

[image]

Thus you should say

```
\setlength{\cftbeforeXskip}{<length>}
```

and, specializing to your case,

```
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{4pt}
```

Comment: That code is from an Overleaf template, and it seems to work except when the minted package is loaded (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/technical-document-template/mdgftpdfbvbs)

Comment: @user668074 I see nothing of that kind in the code.

Comment: sorry, wrong template, I meant this one https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/nist-technical-note-template/gjytbtqtpsmt

Comment: @user668074 It's wrong nonetheless. Report to the Overleaf staff.